# Labor market supply optimization

Tags: labor-economics

How do I optimise this type of problem? 
I have read something about applying the chain rule to find the first order condition but can't imagine how to express it or solve it.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

As you requested, I will just give you a hint and let you proceed from there.

The agent's choice variable is the number of working hours $w$ that he provides in a day. If he works $w$ hours,

- he earns $w$ euros and therefore consumes a quantity $Y=w$ of goods (there is no savings in your problem, so all income is spent on consumption).
- he has $L=24-w$ hours of leisure.

Thus, how can you write the agent's total utility from working $w$ hours?

Comment: I'm going to need more than that I think :)

Comment: @itsjpv You need to show some effort first, we are not a homework-doing machine. Please read our [policy](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions) on homework questions and our general [FAQ](http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).